# set a google sheet to use formulas in english

Tags: google-sheets

I am a portuguese speaker, and this unfortunately means that some of my google sheets try to use formulas in portuguese

Once this happens, what I do is to change my google config to only english, so that I can create a new sheet and the formulas are in english

But there must be a better way! Given a sheet that is already using formulas in portuguese, how can I convert it to english?

---

How do I know the formulas are not in english?

I use the formula `=IFERROR(1+2,"banana")`. If it returns ERROR instead of 3, the sheet is not processing english formulas (it should never, afaik, return banana. But my test is about a cell with ERROR written in it)

Comment: See https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515#change_function_language&zippy=%2Cchange-the-language-for-functions

Answer (score 1):

In Google Sheets, the spreadsheet **locale** determines things like whether to use a comma or a period as a decimal mark, whether to use semicolons or commas as function argument separators, and how to format dates and currencies.

Function names can be shown in the local language of many of the locales, and there is an option to display them in English.

The test formula you mention will give an `#ERROR!` when the spreadsheet's locale uses semicolons as function argument separator, and a `#NAME?` error when the locale uses a comma as a function argument separator but a localized name for the `iferror()` function. It will not give an error when the locale uses commas and happens to use `iferror()` for `iferror()`, even though other function names may still be localized in that locale. It is thus not a reliable test.

To view and set the locale and the function names language, choose **File > Spreadsheet settings**. See [Set a spreadsheet’s location & calculation settings](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515#change_function_language&zippy=%2Cchange-the-language-for-functions%2Cchange-locale-and-time-zone).